# Does Italian always use the infinitive where English uses the gerund?

Tags: word-usage, infinitive, english-comparison

A phrase like "**asking** questions is a sign of a curious mind" is translated in Italian as ***fare** domande è segno di una mente curiosa*; the difference is clearly that English uses the gerund where Italian uses the infinitive.

Does Italian always use the infinitive where English uses the gerund?

The only case where this *rule* doesn't seem to apply is with *giocando si impara*, which is the translation of "you learn by playing." I would not say *giocare si impara*.
Is there any reason for using *giocando* in this case?

Comment: It's a gerund (a form that is derived from a verb but that functions as a noun), since in English a gerund ends in _-ing_. That is what _asking_ is in "Do you mind my asking you?"

Comment: “Asking” in the example of the OP is indeed a gerund, but not all uses of “-ing” forms are gerunds. Wikipedia article about gerund (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) is quite good; see in particular the section “Distinction from other uses of the -ing form” for the difference between actual gerunds and verbal nouns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no “rule” such as the one you suggest. An English gerund might often correspond to an Italian noun (“running is a healthy sport” > “la corsa è uno sport salutare”), or some phrase not involving an infinitive (“seeing is believing” > “se lo vedi, ci credi”; you *might* say “vedere è credere”, but it would sound wooden and as a calque from English), and even an Italian gerund, as in the sentence you quote, which is not at all unique.

In general, in Italian a subordinate phrase with a gerund often expresses a cause, a hypothesis, a way of doing something (as in your example) and the like, so it may correspond to English gerunds introduced by “by”, “while” and so on. Say, “while returning from work, I saw...” > “tornando dal lavoro, ho visto...” but also “mentre tornavo dal lavoro ho visto...”

(Finally, “giocare si impara” is meaningless; if you were forced at gunpoint to use an infinitive you'd say something like “col giocare si impara”, but it would sound horrid.)

Comment: On the other hand "volere è potere" is correct and used, but only on its own

Answer (score 7):

In *giocando si impara*, *giocando* is a ‘complemento di mezzo‘ or di ‘modo’; you would say, instead, *giocare è divertente*; on the other hand you'd say *il bello del giocare è il divertimento* (*the good of playing is the fun*).

The gerund has a meaning of cause, time, medium or mode. So for a specification you need the infinitive.

This is a cause of several errors when trying to translate Italian in English (or conversely): *Questo è spesso causa di errori provando a tradurre l'italiano in inglese* can have the gerund, because time is involved (*quando si prova*). But *trying one's best in translating from Italian to English* should be *fare del proprio meglio traducendo dall'italiano all'inglese*.